# Wi-Fi設定プロファイルを削除したにも関わらず、 NEHotspotConfigurationError.systemConfiguration が 返ってきます。

Tags: swift, ios, xcode, objective-c, wifi

インストール済みのWi-Fi設定プロファイルを削除したにも関わらず、削除したWi-Fi設定のアクセスポイントにNEHotspotConfigurationManager.apply を実行すると NEHotspotConfigurationError.systemConfiguration が 返ってきます。

現象発生手順

1. AというアクセスポイントのWi-Fi設定プロファイルをインストール
2. AというアクセスポイントのWi-Fi設定プロファイルを削除
3. アプリから、以下のコードを実行

   ```
   let accsessPointAConfig = NEHotspotConfiguration(ssid: A.ssid, passphrase: A.pass, isWEP: false)
   NEHotspotConfigurationManager.shared.apply(accsessPointAConfig)
   ```
4. この時以下のエラーが返る

   ```
   NEHotspotConfigurationError.systemConfiguration( = 10)
   ```

以下の現象も発生しました。

- Wi-Fi設定プロファイルを削除したにもかかわらず、設定.appからアクセスポイントAに接続ができた
- 設定.app→Wi-Fi設定→詳細画面にて、「このネットワークを削除する」ボタンが表示されなかった

この現象は稀に起こり、発生する原因は不明です。
iOSのバグでしょうか？